# Intermittent error messages when running an Azure Functions app

Tags: powershell, credentials, azure-function-app

I have a Powershell program which runs on a schedule in an Azure Functions app. It connects to Office 365 to download audit logs, make some changes and then export a CSV to an Azure Data Lake Storage account. To avoid hard-coded credentials, an Azure Key Vault stores the secrets. I created a managed identity in the Azure Function along with the required application settings and URL to point to Azure Key Vault. The code references the application secrets (APPSETTING) and all seemed to be running well, until I noticed today that since yesterday afternoon the exported CSV files were empty.

So I opened up the Function app, hit Run manually and I could see a CSV file exported with data. When I took a look at the execution log however, I spotted these error messages which despite not affecting the execution this time, makes me wonder whether this is what caused the problem with the empty CSV files. The program is now running on a schedule as normal and the error messages appear to be intermittent.

[image]

Not sure why it's complaining about the username and password, when it is clearly able to access the data source (Office audit logs), export the CSV and transfer it to the file destination (Azure Data Lake Storage) successfully.

Any idea what is going on? Any tips or suggestions welcome! Code provided below. Many thanks!

```
  # Input bindings are passed in via param block.
    param($Timer)

    # Get the current universal time in the default string format.
    $currentUTCtime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()

    # The 'IsPastDue' property is 'true' when the current function invocation is later than scheduled.
    if ($Timer.IsPastDue) {
        Write-Host "PowerShell timer is running late!"
    }

    # Write an information log with the current time.
    Write-Host "PowerShell timer trigger function ran! TIME: $currentUTCtime"

    <# 
    Title: Power BI Audit Logging 
    Client: 

    Description: Connects to Azure audit logs using admin credentials (secrets via Azure Key Vault). Opens a session to iterate through the Audit Log ($currentrResults) and aggregate 
    the logs into a single object ($aggregateResults). A for-each loop then iterates through the $aggregateResults and assigns each data piece (datum)
    to a PowerShell object to which properties are added to hold the audit data. A CSV file is created and exported, and then transferred to a Data Lake storage account (using SAS secret via Azure Key Vault). 

    Last Revision: 06/09/2020 #>

    Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
    Set-Item ENV:\SuppressAzurePowerShellBreakingChangeWarnings "true"

    # Better for scheduled jobs
    $uSecret = $ENV:APPSETTING_SecretUsername
    $pSecret = $ENV:APPSETTING_SecretPassword 
    $sasSecret = $ENV:APPSETTING_SecretSAS

    $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pSecret -AsPlainText -Force

    $UserCredential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $uSecret, $securePassword

    # This will prompt the user for credential (optional)
    # $UserCredential = Get-Credential

    $session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
    Import-PSSession $session

    $startDate=(get-date).AddDays(-10)
    $endDate=(get-date)
    $scriptStart=(get-date)

    $sessionName = (get-date -Format 'u')+'pbiauditlog'
    # Reset user audit accumulator
    $aggregateResults = @()
    $i = 0 # Loop counter
    Do { 
        $currentResults = Search-UnifiedAuditLog -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $enddate -SessionId $sessionName -SessionCommand ReturnLargeSet -ResultSize 1000 -RecordType PowerBIAudit
        if ($currentResults.Count -gt 0) {
            Write-Host ("Finished {3} search #{1}, {2} records: {0} min" -f [math]::Round((New-TimeSpan -Start $scriptStart).TotalMinutes,4), $i, $currentResults.Count, $user.UserPrincipalName )
            # Accumulate the data.
            $aggregateResults += $currentResults
            # No need to do another query if the # records returned <1000 - should save around 5-10 seconds per user.
            if ($currentResults.Count -lt 1000) {
                $currentResults = @()
            } else {
                $i++
            }
        }
    } Until ($currentResults.Count -eq 0) # End of Session Search Loop.

    $data=@()

    foreach ($auditlogitem in $aggregateResults) {
        $datum = New-Object -TypeName PSObject  
        $d = ConvertFrom-json $auditlogitem.AuditData
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Id -Value $d.Id
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CreationTDateTime -Value $d.CreationDate
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CreationTime -Value $d.CreationTime
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name RecordType -Value $d.RecordType
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Operation -Value $d.Operation
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name OrganizationId -Value $d.OrganizationId
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UserType -Value $d.UserType
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UserKey -Value $d.UserKey
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Workload -Value $d.Workload
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UserId -Value $d.UserId
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ClientIPAddress -Value $d.ClientIPAddress
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UserAgent -Value $d.UserAgent
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Activity -Value $d.Activity
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ItemName -Value $d.ItemName
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name WorkSpaceName -Value $d.WorkSpaceName
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DashboardName -Value $d.DashboardName
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DatasetName -Value $d.DatasetName
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ReportName -Value $d.ReportName
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name WorkspaceId -Value $d.WorkspaceId
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ObjectId -Value $d.ObjectId
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DashboardId -Value $d.DashboardId
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DatasetId -Value $d.DatasetId
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ReportId -Value $d.ReportId
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name OrgAppPermission -Value $d.OrgAppPermission
            
        # Option to include the below JSON column however for large amounts of data it may be difficult for PBI to parse
        $datum | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Datasets -Value (ConvertTo-Json $d.Datasets)
        
        # Below is a simple PowerShell statement to grab one of the entries and place in the DatasetName if any exist
        foreach ($dataset in $d.datasets) {
            $datum.DatasetName = $dataset.DatasetName
            $datum.DatasetId = $dataset.DatasetId
        }
        $data+=$datum
    }

    $dateTimestring = $startDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "_" + (Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd") + "_" + (Get-Date -Format "HHmm")
    $fileName = ($dateTimestring + ".csv")
    Write-Host ("Writing to file {0}" -f $fileName) 
    $filePath = "$Env:temp/" + $fileName
    $data | Export-csv -Path $filePath

    # File transfer to Azure storage account 
    Get-AzContext #Connect-AzAccount -Credential $UserCredential
    Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "Audit" -status
    $Context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "auditingstorage" -StorageAccountKey $sasSecret
    Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Force -Context $Context -Container "auditlogs" -File $filePath -Blob $filename 

    # Close PowerShell session
    Remove-PSSession -Id $Session.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error state

> ERROR: Connect-AzAccount : Username + Password authentication is not
> supported in PowerShell Core.  Please use device code authentication
> for interactive log in, or Service Principal authentication for script
> log in.

The problem come from using the **credential** authentication scheme in Powershell Core

```
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $UserCredential
```

Instead, in your app, enable the **System Managed Identity** and grant it the permissions to access what you need.

You can do that by going into the **Identity** pane and turning the **status** to **On**  in the **System assigned** tab.

From there, add the required access through the **Azure role assignments** button.

Once this is done, you don't need to use `Connect-AzAccount`, your app is connected automatically to the managed identity at runtime. You can use **Object ID** from the **Identity** pane to find it afterward in **Azure Active Directory / App Registration** and assign it additional **API** access if needed.

**Additional note**
You could always continue to use **Connect-AzAccount** with a service principal account but unless you have requirements for that, I'd go the **Managed Identity** route.

**References**

[How to use managed Identities for App Service and Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet)

[Create an Azure service principal with Azure Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/create-azure-service-principal-azureps?view=azps-4.6.1&viewFallbackFrom=azps-4.2.0)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I already had a system-assigned identity set up with owner permissions to Azure Key Vault and Azure Data Lake Storage. I understand the theory why we don't need to use Connect-AzConnect as the managed identity should set the context so I deleted the line `Connect-AzAccount -Credential $UserCredential` and ran the program again, and this time it presented the following error: **ERROR: No account found in the context. Please login using Connect-AzAccount.Exception** Does this mean I should try the service principal route or should I persevere with a managed identity?

Comment: @MAK What line did produce this error ? Did you give enough permission to the account to the the AZ statement afterward using the Azure Role assignement. What happens if you just put Get-AzContext where your connect-azaccount was ? Does it produce a context or does it give an error right away ?

Comment: There are two error messages. Both may or may not be related so I'll link both of them here. Bear in mind however, that the process has been successfully outputting the CSV files with data nonetheless but I want to address the errors raised in the execution logs, as they may cause issues later. [Error 1](https://imgur.com/a/ffu0zSs) and [Error 2](https://imgur.com/a/YGXUwsH). Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have pasted in the updated code in the main post. I tried `Get-AzContext` where `Connect-AzAccount -Credential $UserCredential` used to be, but it did not provide any context information in the terminal window. It threw up the two errors mentioned, and then proceeded to output the files to the storage account.

Comment: Error 1 was because of the line `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`. I changed this to `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`.

Comment: Error 2 came up in the logs (although not blocking the program run) because it was trying to connect using credentials rather than identity. Changing this to `Connect-AzAccount -Identity` forces a connection using the managed identity. Although it does seem this isn't necessary because evidently `$Context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "pbiauditingstorage" -StorageAccountKey $sasSecret` was able to connect with the right context, but to avoid the error in the logs and to make it a little more elegant, I opted for the forced connection in the end.

Comment: @MAK Regarding Error #2, don't you have this already setup in the Function App Profile.ps1 ? My function apps does by default. Ideally, you put it in the profile.ps1 of the function App so the connection is made on the first cold start everytime but not at each function call if the app is still started. See: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/blob/dev/src/Azure.Functions.Cli/StaticResources/profile.ps1 Since for me it was there by default, I didn't think of it.